# Getting the contents of a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, hash, ruby-on-rails-3.1

```
{"test_url"=>"http://test.com/123.jpg"}
```

is my output from

```
<% @results.each do |t| %>
    <%= t.image.extract!("test_url") %>
<% end %>
```

How can i just get the contents of test_url? so http://test.com/123.jpg

Comment: if `h = {"test_url"=>"http://test.com/123.jpg"}` you can simply get the content with `h["test_url"]`,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#extract! always deletes and returns the key/value pairs for the given key from the Hash.

To delete and only return the value:

```
<%= t.image.delete("test_url") %>
```

or, if you just want to get the value:

```
<%= t.image["test_url"] %>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<% @results.each do |t| %>
    <%= t.image["test_url"] %>
<% end %>
```